# Is possible to retrieve RSA d knowing m, c, e , n?

Tags: encryption, rsa

I have a scenario that has this type of security:

1. System `A` generates a random number and sends it to `B`
2. `B` hashes of that value and encrypts it with RSA, then it sends the result to `A`
3. `A` decrypts via RSA and validates the hash with the one calculated at the moment of random number generation.

The RSA calculation that is made by `A` is  `m = c^e (MOD N)` so I know:

```
m - the clear message
c - the encrypted message
e - exponent (e=3)
n - modulus
```

Is it possible for `A` to find `d` and generate the `c` message from `B`? `c` is well padded.

Answer (score 1):

'decrypting' with e and apparently 'encrypting' with d are not encryption at all, they are signing and verifying; there are dozens of Qs explaining these are not the same. So your question really is, can A forge B's RSA signature?

So far as is known by people who can answer you, only if n can be factored, and that is only possible if either it is too small (currently about 1024 bits or less) or it was generated defectively (see Debian and factorable.net among others) or someday quantum computers work at scale.

However if B uses a poor hash A might be able to find two claimed-random numbers that give the same hash, and thus obtain a signature on x1 that also functions as a signature on x2 != x1, which might or might not be a problem for your 'scenario' since it has no stated goals.